# How to create Unix tarball with various file permissions inside on a Windows box?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, tar

Could anyone enlighten me on how can I create a regular Unix tarball archive (e.g., `tar.gz` or `tar.bz2`) on a Windows box in a way that will mark some files in that archive as "executable" (e.g., with permission flags set like `-rwxr-xr-x`, 0755) and some files as non-executable (e.g., with something like `-rw-r--r--`, 0644)?

I know that one can use:

- [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org) to create tarballs using a Windows box, but it seems that it can't set custom flags on certain files when doing a tarball and sets everything as `-rwxrwxrwx`, 0777.
- Normal GNU utilities port (such as [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com)), which require one to do some command line magic - that's perfectly ok for me, but could be bothersome for some users.
- Remote or virtual Linux/BSD installation and then again, use normal `tar` / `gzip` / `bzip2` commands.

Any more user-friendly solutions?